# Split the data of splunk query with number pattern

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

I am preparing a dashboard the type of URLs been invoked for my service in Splunk dashboard.

the URLs are like below in my splunk query .

**Query -** `index=myIndex serviceName="serviceName" | eval _raw=replace(_raw, "\\", "") | eval URI=mvindex(split(URI,"?"),0) | stats values(URI),count  by HttpStatus`

```
 /myIndex/v1/serviceName/actuator/health
/myIndex/v1/serviceName/service/order
/myIndex/v1/serviceName/service/account
/myIndex/v1/serviceName/service/getData
/myIndex/v1/serviceName/service/lookupService/%2086406
/myIndex/v1/serviceName/service/lookupService/01364
/myIndex/v1/serviceName/service/lookupService/01840
/myIndex/v1/serviceName/service/lookupService/01906
/myIndex/v1/serviceName/service/lookupService/02119
/myIndex/v1/serviceName/service/lookupService/02148
/myIndex/v1/serviceName/service/lookupService/02382
```

Can you suggest me how to consider  the URL till lookupService by ignoring the different numbers after that .

Ideally for  lookupService I need to get the count as 7 here like below

```
/myIndex/v1/serviceName/service/lookupService - 7
```

Comment: what is your purpose in replacing escaped backslashes in `_raw`? You're promptly ignoring `_raw` in the rest of your search.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`rex`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SCS/current/SearchReference/RexCommandExamples) and extract the base URL without the trailing slash and digits (and percent from encoded space `%20`)

```
index=myIndex serviceName="serviceName" 
| eval _raw=replace(_raw, "\\", "") 
| eval URI=mvindex(split(URI,"?"),0) 
| rex field=URI "(<?URI>.+)(\/[%0-9]+)?"
| stats values(URI), count by HttpStatus
```

Comment: better: `| eval URL=replace(URI,"\/[\%\d]+$","")`

Comment: its worked perfectly